# Advanced Custom Fields [Post Object - Auto Draft]

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've created an advanced custom field with the field type of post object. I somehow load all the data in the list but the data it shows is Auto draft. How can I output the proper data? Thanks

[image: here is the ss of my dashboard]

Answer (score 1):

```
function my_relationship_filter( $args, $field, $post_id )
{
    $args['post_status'] = array('publish');
    return $args;
}

add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/query', 'my_relationship_filter', 10, 3);
```

Thanks for good question. For me helps this code.